# Instantiating NSFetchedResultsController terminating with uncaught exception

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am instantiating a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a fetchRequest of an abstract class:

```
private func setupFetchController() {
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = SearchEntity.fetchRequest()
    let fetchController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    self.fetchController = fetchController
}
```

The `SearchEntity` is an abstract parent class of `Person` and `Group`. I used this to be able to fetch 2 entities with 1 `NSFetchedResultsController`. However the app crashes when this function is called:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I have narrowed it down to uncommenting and commenting the creation of the `NSFetchedResultsController`. I have 2 more of these functions with exactly the same style which work.

What am I doing/is going wrong?

edit: to Add to this. I am able to manually fetch the `SearchEntity` by just using `context.performFetch(...)` which gives me correct results. However, hence the name, I'm going to search it so I need to be able to update efficiently.

edit2:

Example of same function elsewhere that is functioning:

```
private func setupFetchController() {
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Person.fetchRequest()

    // Sort Persons
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor2]

    // Filter Persons (only iType = 1)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "iType == %i", 1)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    // Create the FetchController
    let fetchController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionName", cacheName: nil)
    self.fetchController = fetchController
}
```

Comment: You said as: " I have 2 more of these functions with exactly the same style which work. " What did you mean? And both functions are the same type? I mean they're FRC functions?

Comment: I'll add them to the OP, They are also instantiating a FetchResultsController but with a different entity.

Comment: The only difference is not adding sortDescriptors / predicates

Comment: They're works as expected?

Comment: Yep those other functions are working as expected, just the one fetching the parent entity: SearchEntity is crashing. It is strange that it throws no exception since it is a class Apple provided.

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint. You will get the reason and the clear error message: *An instance of NSFetchedResultsController **requires a fetch request with sort descriptors***

Comment: Setting sort descriptors works! If you post your comment as an answer i'll mark the question answered :-) Thanks very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the exception because at least one sort descriptor is required.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller):

> You typically create an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` as an
>   instance variable of a table view controller. When you initialize the
>   fetch results controller, you provide four parameters:
>
> 1) A fetch request. **This must contain at least one sort descriptor to
>   order the results**.
>
> 2) A managed object context. The controller uses this context to execute
>   the fetch request.
>
> 3) Optionally, a key path on result objects that returns the section
>   name. The controller uses the key path to split the results into
>   sections (passing nil indicates that the controller should generate a
>   single section).
>
> 4) Optionally, the name of the cache file the controller should use
>   (passing `nil` prevents caching). Using a cache can avoid the overhead
>   of computing the section and index information.